# Specifying multiple PYTHONPATH values in MinGW

Tags: python-2.7, mingw, mingw-w64

Say I've got a file (`foo.py`) that prints the `sys.path`:

```
# from path.to.folder import foo
# from another.path.to.folder import bar

import sys

for p in sys.path:
    print(p)
```

My issue is that you uncomment the `import` statements and run the file through MingW64 (in my case, Git Bash) - Python will not be able to locate the modules correctly, yielding an `ImportError`.

Running the file with the imports commented out yields this output:

```
user@host MINGW64 /
$ export PYTHONPATH="C:\path\to\folder:C:\another\path\to\folder"
$ python foo.py

C:\some\path
C:\path\to\folder:C:\another\path\to\folder
C:\Windows\system32\python27.zip
C:\Python\2.7.12\DLLs
C:\Python\2.7.12\lib
C:\Python\2.7.12\lib\plat-win
C:\Python\2.7.12\lib\lib-tk
C:\Python\2.7.12
```

The problem seems to be that MinGW is not interpreting `export PYTHONPATH="C:\path\to\folder:C:\another\path\to\folder"` as two separate paths. It passes a single malformed path to Python, which doesn't know what to do with it.

MinGW's [Posix path conversion](http://www.mingw.org/wiki/Posix_path_conversion) documentation does not appear to cover this scenario, but I would think this is an incredibly common use case.

How do I set the `PYTHONPATH` environmental variable in MinGW such that it sends two paths along to Python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the [Posix path conversion documentation](http://www.mingw.org/wiki/Posix_path_conversion) *does* cover this case:

> Arguments containing a ; are considered to be Windows path lists and are not converted.

Converting the middle colon to a semi-colon fixes the issue:

`export PYTHONPATH="C:\path\to\folder;C:\another\path\to\folder"`